# How does Pyro perform operations with Random Variables?

Tags: pytorch, probability-theory, pyro

In Pyro there is a new experimental container class: [Random Variables](https://docs.pyro.ai/en/1.8.0/contrib.randomvariable.html#)

Using Random Variables you can write something like this:

```py
from pyro.distributions.torch import Normal

X = Normal(5, 1).rv
Y = Normal(20, 3).rv

Z = 3*X + Y
```

where X,Y,Z are distributions.

What is the mathematical foundation behind the '+' operation between Random Variables?
I can imagine that multiplying with a constant number is pretty trivial,
but what about performing operations with an RV?
For example, in Probability Theory we have the [Circular Convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_convolution).

I searched the documentation but I got lost in the Pyro-pyTorch connection.

Comment: It is related to the [convolution of probability distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_of_probability_distributions).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you provide me with the relative context in the Pyro documentation?

Answer (score 0):

The relevant section for addition is here https://github.com/pyro-ppl/pyro/blob/53cfeaa5f6a3a92231bf8ad60a9ea69e5f10aad6/pyro/contrib/randomvariable/random_variable.py#L24-L27

```py
def __add__(self, x: Union[float, Tensor]):
    return RandomVariable(
        TransformedDistribution(self.distribution, AffineTransform(x, 1))
    )
```

Other arithmetic operations are also in this file.